# Trying to forward a HTTP responce from a server to a browser in Java. But, when I open the site in the browser, the result is 'octet-stream'

Tags: java, sockets, http, https

I have a socket open with the Web Browser, my application serves as a proxy, I have already collected the HTTP request the web browser made and have opened a socket with the remote server for the website. In this case, I'm connecting to the remote server of [www.neverssl.com](http://www.neverssl.com), which is a HTTP (not HTTPS) connection:

```
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(serverAddress);
        Socket remoteServerSocket = new Socket(addr, 80);
```

Then I tell the browser that connection has been established:

```
        browserClient.getOutputStream().write(CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED.getBytes());
        browserClient.getOutputStream().flush();
```

The fullHTTPRequest is just a typical HTTP request that I'm sending on to the appropriate server, I'll include the actual string passed to this below:

```
        remoteServerSocket.getOutputStream().write(fullHTTPRequest.getBytes());
        remoteServerSocket.getOutputStream().flush();
```

And now I'm just reading from one input stream and passing it to the output stream (i.e. remote server to web browser):

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        do {
            read = remoteServerSocket.getInputStream().read(buffer);
            if (read > 0) {
                browserClient.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, read);
                if (remoteServerSocket.getInputStream().available() < 1) {
                    browserClient.getOutputStream().flush();
                }
            }
        } while (read >= 0);
```

The full string HTTP request as mentioned above (I've double checked that \r\n are all the line endings and \r\n\r\n comes after the whole block:

```
GET http://www.neverssl.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.neverssl.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

And (after changing my program so that the responce it printed out on the console), I can see that this is what the above reading do-while loop is producing into the browser output stream:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 22:29:21 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Sun, 14 Mar 2021 01:21:37 GMT
ETag: W/"e8bb9152091d61caa9d69fed8c4aebc6"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 8dcd559356fc30961462110a6153f8b2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: DUB2-C1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: AiIx_Z1GbMae5ssJOV9IsWNf3zcyMkgp1BP2wjKM0-KwKLjUSGrOZg==
Age: 41501

4b8
ﾋ  [a lot of gibberish characters after this, which I'm assuming is the HTML from the website in some form, I just don't know what]
```

So after all this I'm expecting/hoping to get a normal HTML webpage in my web-browser. But instead, opening the webpage gives me an option to download an 'octet-stream', which is obviously no good to me. I don't understand why I am not getting a normal HTTP page on my browser. I've also tried using BufferedReaders for the .getInputStream() and BufferedWriters for the .getOutputStream() respectively, so that they were producing characters instead of bytes, but it doesn't seem to have done any good. Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I tell the browser that connection has been established:

It looks like you are confusing the response to a HTTP CONNECT  request used for `https://` URL, with the response for a plain HTTP proxy request. While you obviously have a plain `http://` connection you apply the semantics valid only for the `https://` connection, which is wrong.

With CONNECT the client sends the CONNECT request to the proxy, the proxy establishes a connection to the given server and then accepts the CONNECT request (i.e. CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED). After that the proxy will just forward any data between client and server.

With a normal HTTP proxy request instead the proxy will **adjust the request** by changing the [absolute URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.2) in the request to an [absolute path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1). This modified request will then be forwarded to the server. **The proxy will not issue its own response to the clients request.**  Instead the proxy will just send the response received from the server to the client.

In your code a CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED instead is sent wrongly to a plain HTTP proxy request. This is not expected and will be interpreted of the HTTP response header from the server, so that the real HTTP response header and body will be wrongly interpreted together as HTTP response body. Since no `Content-Type` is given in the wrong HTTP response header (i.e. the CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED) it will just guess what it might be, in this case it will guess `application/octet-stream` which basically means "unknown binary data".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Really got that breakthrough feeling from this answer!